# Is there a way to simulate user input in the background

Tags: python, automation, user-input

I'm searching for a programming language or python plugin to simulate user input, like clicking a button in a application(a bit like the python plugin 'Selenium'). The problem i have is, that I would like to have the application running in the background, so that I can still use my PC while the program is running.
Sorry if the question is vague, i just don't know where to start.

Comment: Isn't "still using your PC" going to require control over the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> simulate user input, like clicking a button in a application

I suggest taking look at [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/), it allows you to cause mouse move, mouse click, keyboard write and so on. It is cross-platform. I do not know if it will met your *have the application running in the background* requirement on all platforms you must support.